# Подключение средствами PHP к FTP

Tags: ftp, php

Я могу видеть папки сервера через ftp. Как можно получить список каталогов? И можно также просматривать, как и функцией `scandir()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень полезная информация, именно прочитав ее решил такой же вопрос! [Функции FTP](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.ftp.php)